# Python scapy SOMEIP protocol showing the key not value of a field

Tags: python, scapy, ethernet

When printing SOMEIP packets with `.summary` fields show the value not the key of the field dictionary. For example we've got a field named `msg_type`, when using `.summary`, the value of the packet field is printed (`NOTIFICATION`,`REQUEST`..) but when using `packet.msg_type` the key of the field (`2`,`3`...) is shown.

How can I print the value using the second method?

Answer (score 0):

`msg_type` is a `ByteEnumField`, and you can access the value type in this way-

```
from scapy.contrib.automotive import someip
s = someip.SOMEIP(msg_type=0x0)    
type_val = someip.SOMEIP.msg_type.i2s[s.msg_type]
```

and the output-

```
In [15]: type_val
Out[15]: 'REQUEST'
```

Comment: Even better, you can do `s.sprintf("%msg_type%")`